# Need help xslt 1.0 grouping for mapping stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, grouping

Working on a xslt 1.0 stylesheet for mapping of an address service. I have lookup up some of the examples for the Muenchian method for grouping in xslt 1.0, but i still am confused on the xsl:key and nested xsl:for-each loops.

I am only concerned with the `InputAddress` node-set. There may be multiple (but not always) `InputAddress` nodesets as part of the parent `ValidateRequest` node so i need to loop thru all iterations of `InputAddress` and then perform the mapping to the pertinent elements.

#### source xml

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v1="blah" xmlns:v3="blah2">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <v1:validate>
        <ValidateRequest>
            <!--One or more repetitions:-->
            <InputAddress>
                <v3:City>Redmond</v3:City>
                <v3:Territory>
                    <v3:Name>Washington</v3:Name>
                    <FIPSStateAlphaCode>WA</FIPSStateAlphaCode>
                </v3:Territory>
                <v3:PostalCode>98007</v3:PostalCode>
                <v3:Country>
                    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                    <v3:Name>US</v3:Name>
                </v3:Country>
                <v3:FullAddress>123 main street</v3:FullAddress>
                <v3:FullAddress>Ste 200</v3:FullAddress>
            </InputAddress>
            <InputAddress>
                <v3:City>Seattle</v3:City>
                <v3:Territory>
                    <v3:Name>Washington</v3:Name>
                    <FIPSStateAlphaCode>WA</FIPSStateAlphaCode>
                </v3:Territory>
                <v3:PostalCode>98103</v3:PostalCode>
                <v3:Country>
                    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                    <v3:Name>US</v3:Name>
                </v3:Country>
                <v3:FullAddress>987 1st street</v3:FullAddress>
            </InputAddress>
        </ValidateRequest>
    </v1:validate>
</soap:Body>
```

#### expected result

```
    <soap:Body>
    <wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequest>
        <wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequestElement>
            <wsdl:Address_Line1>123 main street</wsdl:Address_Line1>
            <wsdl:Address_Line2>Ste 200</wsdl:Address_Line2>
            <wsdl:City>Redmond</wsdl:City>
            <wsdl:State>WA</wsdl:State>
            <wsdl:Postal_Code>98007</wsdl:Postal_Code>
            <wsdl:Country>US</wsdl:Country>
        </wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequestElement>
        <wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequestElement>
            <wsdl:Address_Line1>987 1st Street</wsdl:Address_Line1>
            <wsdl:City>Seattle</wsdl:City>
            <wsdl:State>WA</wsdl:State>
            <wsdl:Postal_Code>98103</wsdl:Postal_Code>
            <wsdl:Country>US</wsdl:Country>
        </wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequestElement>
    </wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

#### and my named template snipet after an xsl:choose(not shown):

```
<xsl:key name="AddressDoctor" match="v3:FullAddress" use="//v3:FullAddress" />
<xsl:variable name="address" select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='validate']/ValidateRequest/InputAddress"/>

<xsl:template name="addressdoctor">
    <soap:Envelope>
        <soap:Header>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Header']/*"/>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequest>

            <xsl:for-each select="key('AddressDoctor', '.')">
                <wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequestElement>
                    <xsl:for-each select="[not($FullAddress = preceding::text()=$FullAddress)]">
                        <xsl:element name="wsdl:{concat('Address_Line',position())}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <wsdl:City>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$address/*[local-name()='City']">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$address/*[local-name()='City']"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    </wsdl:City>
                    <wsdl:State>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$address/*[local-name()='Territory']/*[local-name()='FIPSStateAlphaCode']"/>
                    </wsdl:State>
                    <wsdl:Postal_Code>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$address/*[local-name()='PostalCode']"/>
                    </wsdl:Postal_Code>
                    <wsdl:Country>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$address/*[local-name()='Country']/*[local-name()='Name']"/>
                    </wsdl:Country>
                </wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequestElement>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequest>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you have duplicate `v3:FullAddress` elements? Based on the example input you gave I don't see why you need a grouping function.

Comment: yes i can have multiple `v3:FullAddress` elements, but i mainly want to keep the `wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequestElement` nodeset together as it can have multiple iterations, before sending the request to the SP. If i just run a `for-each` on each node, i get the value of each node, in each iteration of `wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequestElement`, in other words, the iterations are not unique.

Comment: Please show an actual, accurate sample of your XML document. For the current one there is indeed no need for grouping.

Comment: Mathias, the current XML source tree i have in the post is the most accurate representation of what i am trying to work with. There are 2 `InputAddress` elements, which are parent 'groups' whose child nodes need to be processed independently and 'grouped' with one another. I look at any other of these grouping based questions with xmlt 1.0 and they involve groups of multiple unique parent nodes, so i don't know how my example could not involve the use of a grouping technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input XML you have provided I don't see that there is a need for any type of grouping. Which is a good thing considering you are working with XSLT 1.0 since grouping can be a bit difficult to get right. You can instead start with a simple identity template and then override a few of the elements to display the output you are looking for.

Here is the XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:v1="blah" xmlns:v3="blah2" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ValidateRequest">
    <wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequest>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequest>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="InputAddress">
    <wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequestElement>
      <wsdl:Address_Line1>
        <xsl:value-of select="v3:FullAddress[1]"/>
      </wsdl:Address_Line1>
      <xsl:if test="v3:FullAddress[2]">
        <wsdl:Address_Line2>
          <xsl:value-of select="v3:FullAddress[2]"/>
        </wsdl:Address_Line2>
      </xsl:if>
      <wsdl:City>
        <xsl:value-of select="v3:City"/>
      </wsdl:City>
      <wsdl:State>
        <xsl:value-of select="v3:Territory/FIPSStateAlphaCode"/>
      </wsdl:State>
      <wsdl:Postal_Code>
        <xsl:value-of select="v3:PostalCode"/>
      </wsdl:Postal_Code>
      <wsdl:Country>
        <xsl:value-of select="v3:Country/v3:Name"/>
      </wsdl:Country>
    </wsdl:WS_MDM_Address_ValidationRequestElement>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="v1:validate">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will produce the output that you are looking for based on the example you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew, this is great, i now understand that this is a much simpler task than i originally understood. Thank you much!!